# Tensorflow loss function using both image and masks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, loss-function

I am trying to train an image segmentation network. I want to make a custom loss that apart from `y_true` (ground truth mask) and `y_pred` (predicted mask), it will be based also on the grayscale image (of the current training image/batch).

How can I do that?

I have not tried any code.

Answer (score 0):

## Update:

In my understanding, you want to use a custom loss function that uses a loss function with 3 inputs. Generally, in TF/keras [custom loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss#:%7E:text=Was%20this%20helpful%3F-,tf.keras.losses.Loss,-bookmark_border) functions require to have 2 inputs, i.e. `custom_loss(y_true,y_pred)`. If you want to provide multiple labels inside a custom loss function there are quite a few workarounds for this.

One simplest and most effective one is to use a `lambda` function to provide all your inputs for the loss function while compiling the model.

### Example Code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, images):
    cross_ent_loss = categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    image_loss = tf.reduce_mean(images)
    total_loss = cross_ent_loss + 0.1 * image_loss  # adjust weighting as desired
    return total_loss

input_shape = (32, 32, 3)
num_classes = 10

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, model.input))
```

---

**If this is helpful please accept this answer by clicking the tick synmbol.**

---

There is more than one way to create a custom loss function that takes into account the grayscale image, you can define a function that takes three inputs: y_true, y_pred, and the grayscale image. Here's an example implementation:

```py
def custom_loss(grayscale_weight=0.1):

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):

        def grayscale_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            # Calculate the mean squared error between the grayscale image and predicted mask
            grayscale = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(tf.cast(x_train, tf.float32))
            grayscale = tf.image.resize(grayscale, (y_pred.shape[1], y_pred.shape[2]))
            grayscale_loss = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(grayscale, y_pred)

            return grayscale_weight * grayscale_loss

        # Calculate the binary cross-entropy loss between the ground truth mask and predicted mask
        bce_loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

        # Add the grayscale loss to the binary cross-entropy loss
        loss = bce_loss + grayscale_loss(y_true, y_pred)

        return loss

    return loss
```

In this example, the custom loss function takes a grayscale_weight argument that controls the weight of the grayscale loss relative to the binary cross-entropy loss. The loss function first defines a grayscale_loss function that calculates the mean squared error between the grayscale image and predicted mask. It then calculates the binary cross-entropy loss between the ground truth mask and predicted mask using the binary_crossentropy function provided by Keras. Finally, it adds the grayscale loss to the binary cross-entropy loss with the appropriate weight. The resulting loss function is then used to compile the model.

```
# Define your model
model = ...
```

```
# Compile the model with the custom loss function
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss(grayscale_weight=0.1))
```

.

Comment: Thank you for your example implementation. However, how does `x_train` get updated each time the loss function is called. `x_train` must be the current image batch. So, I am I am still trying to figure it out and it appears that it might be possible using Keras' `train_on_batch`. I will update my question if/when I find it.

Comment: @JavaJaard Please check the updated **Answer** now. Hope this is what you are looking for.